# Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in

Tags: wordpress, themes

Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in /home4/tigas44/public_html/wp-content/themes/cardealer/includes/menus/menus.php on line 67

can be seen at:
http://firstnationsautomobileapproved.com/

which refers to the following line;

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['cars']) || empty(json_decode($_COOKIE['cars']))) {
```

from the block:

```
$compareClass = "";
if(!isset($_COOKIE['cars']) || empty(json_decode($_COOKIE['cars']))) {
$compareClass = esc_attr(' style=display:none');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [empty()](http://php.net/empty) functions seems to be the cause of your issue. The documentation says the following:

> Prior to PHP 5.5, empty() only supports variables; anything else will
>   result in a parse error. In other words, the following will not work:
>   empty(trim($name)). Instead, use trim($name) == false.

So try to change your code to this:

```
$compareClass = "";
if(!isset($_COOKIE['cars']) || json_decode($_COOKIE['cars']) == false) {
$compareClass = esc_attr(' style=display:none');
}
```